# Factory of generic types in Swift (Protocols and generics)

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm trying to create a factory of generic types that implement a protocol. The problem is that in the `make` method of the adapter factory I get the following error: `Protocol 'Adapter' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`.

Here is an example of what I'm doing now:

```
protocol Adapter {

    typealias T

    static func method1(parameter: T)
}

final class AdapterFactory<T>: NSObject {

    static func make(name: String = "") -> Adapter.Type {

        switch name {

        case "Adapter1":
            return ConcreteAdapter1<T>.self

        default:
            return ConcreteAdapter2<T>.self
        }

    }
}

final class ConcreteAdapter1<T>: NSObject, Adapter {

    static func method1(parameter: T) {
        // bla, bla, bla
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a pattern used in swift standard library(see Sequence and AnySequence) i.e using something like AnyAdapter that implements the Adapter protocol by delegating every method call to the underlying implementation(a concrete implementation of Adapter protocol like ConcreteAdapter1) or by using closures.

Your factory would then return AnyAdapter instead of Adapter. It may seems unnatural at first but using AnyAdapter as the type gives the same advantage as using the protocol (obviously it is a workaround) since AnyAdapter is not a concrete implementation by itself instead it delegates the implementation to a concrete implementation.

Here's the code

```
protocol Adapter {

    typealias Element

    func method1(parameter: Element)

    func method2(parameter : Element)
}




struct AnyAdapter<Element> : Adapter {

    private let _method1 : (Element) -> ()

    private let _method2 : (Element) -> ()


    init<A:Adapter where A.Element == Element>(_ base:A) {
        _method1 = { base.method1($0) }
        _method2 = { base.method2($0) }
    }

    func method1(parameter: Element) {
        _method1(parameter)
    }

    func method2(parameter: Element) {
        _method2(parameter)
    }

}



final class ConcreteAdapter1<T>: NSObject, Adapter {

    func method1(parameter: T) {
        print("Concrete Adapter 1 method 1")
    }

    func method2(parameter: T) {
        print("Concrete Adapter 1 method 2")
    }
}



final class ConcreteAdapter2<T> : Adapter {
    func method1(parameter: T) {
        print("Concrete adapter 2 method 1")
    }

    func method2(parameter: T) {
        print("Concrete Adapter 2 method 2")
    }
}

final class AdapterFactory<T>: NSObject {

    static func make(name: String = "") -> AnyAdapter<String> {

        switch name {


        case "Adapter1":
            let concreteAdapter1 = ConcreteAdapter1<String>()
            return AnyAdapter(concreteAdapter1)

        default:
            let concreteAdapter2 = ConcreteAdapter2<String>()
            return AnyAdapter(concreteAdapter2)
        }

    }
}
```

I am not using a static method in protocol to make things simpler since statics don't operate well with generic types.

To be honest this is a shortcoming in the language and i would like it work like this thing to be simplified like in java or C#.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is hard to understand... If I had other methods in my protocol, how would I call them?

Comment: Found a better way to implement the AnyAdapter in terms of another concrete implementation. Going to update my post. Here i am implementing two methods defined in the protocol. Let me know what you think

Comment: Wow, this works, but it's certainly a lot of juggling to accomplish something that should be simple. I hope Apple fixes this. Thanks! :)

Comment: Let's hope they fix it... generics+protocol, Java can this since 2004, at the same time they introduced generics, t's such a basic feature, if you want to use generics seriously. I mostly end either not using protocols and normal classes classes instead or not using generics. There are a lot of restrictions and weird issues concerning this.